# Why does string concatenation fail when I remove some white space before the apostrophe?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linqpad

This works:

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);
SET @query = 'SELECT j.job FROM ' + '' + 'job as j';

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

...but this does not work (output error is `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as', pointing to the first line`):

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);
SET @query = 'SELECT j.job FROM' + '' + 'job as j'; -- removed the white space after the word FROM

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Why is this?

Comment: Print out the query . . . `FROMjob as j` is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need a space after `from` before `job`.

```
select 'SELECT j.job FROM ' + '' + 'job as j';
```

returns: `SELECT j.job FROM job as j`

```
select 'SELECT j.job FROM' + '' + 'job as j';
```

returns: `SELECT j.job FROMjob as j`